# ASP.NET Classic OWIN StartUp ConfigureServices not called

Tags: asp.net, owin

I am writing a ASP.NET Classic WebAPI application.  I have implemented the OWIN StartUp class, and the Caonfiguration method is executed, however, the ConfigureServices method does not get executed.  I know this works for DotNetCore.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ClassicWebApi.Startup))]

namespace ClassicWebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //CODE IS NOT EXECUTED
        }
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //CODE IS EXECUTED
        }


    }
}
```

Is this only a feature of DotNetCore or do I need to include another library in the set up?

Comment: `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method is only available in ASP.NET Core. Why do you need in ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: I'd like to use the dependency injection.  Specifically the AddDbContext and AddScoped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to use the dependency injection. Specifically the
>   AddDbContext and AddScoped

Build-in dependency injection is only available in ASP.NET Core. You will need to use third party IoC container such as -

- [Autofac for Web API](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html)
- [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)

Comment: I figured that might be the answer.  I was hoping to get to use the  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection library.  I'll continue with Autofac for this one.  Thank you for the response

Comment: This isn't' necessarily true. You can use the Microsoft dependency injection packages with .NET framework

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use DI in ASP.NET using WebAPI then look into Unity.

Unity is the best library out there for adding DI to existing legacy ASP.NET applications.  You can add DI to anything using this, even WebForms.

**Packages:**

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Unity" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Unity.Container" version="5.8.6" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

**Global.ascx:**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UnityConfigWebForms.RegisterComponents(this, AppConfig.WebAppSettings._authType);
        UnityConfigWebAPI.RegisterComponents(AppConfig.WebAppSettings._authType);
        ...existing code...
```

**Example Class:**

```
public static class UnityConfigWebAPI
{
    public static void RegisterComponents(WebAppSettings.AuthenticationTypes authenticationType)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IWesTest, WesTest>(new Unity.Injection.InjectionConstructor("hi wesley, webapi"));

        //container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
        //{
        //    IAuthenticationManager mgr = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        //    System.Type generic = System.Type.GetType("CGI_Automation_Framework.AuthenticationEngines." + authenticationType);
        //    object ad = System.Activator.CreateInstance(generic, mgr);
        //    return ad;
        //}));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

**Example WebAPI Class:**

```
[Authorize]
public class TagController : ApiController
{
    private AppStart.IWesTest _auth;

    public TagController(AppStart.IWesTest auth)
    {
        this._auth = auth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` with non-Core projects.  You'll simply call `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` from Global.asax `Application_Start` method.

Comment: How? Application_Start has no references to IServiceCollection or Startup instances.

Comment: Not enough info to be a useful response. Downvote.