# How to configure services in Owin startup class in ASP.NET framework

Tags: asp.net, owin

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) 
{
    // code is executed 
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    // code is not executed  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method is only available in ASP.NET Core.
this might help- [ASP.NET Classic OWIN StartUp ConfigureServices not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222923/asp-net-classic-owin-startup-configureservices-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [OWIN Startup Class Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection), you have to add the NuGet package `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` and then reference a OWIN Startup class from VisualStudio template, then in the following code you can access OWIN:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("ProductionConfiguration", typeof(StartupDemo.ProductionStartup2))]

namespace StartupDemo
{
    public class ProductionStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                string t = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(t + " Production OWIN App");
            });
        }
    }
    public class ProductionStartup2
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                string t = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(t + " 2nd Production OWIN App");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to apply dependency injection in .net framework web application?

Comment: no following, could you please elaborate?

Comment: how to auto inject the services in webform application class?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
        TimedBackgroundService timedBackground = new TimedBackgroundService();
        timedBackground.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
   }

public class TimedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
 {
  private async Task ExecuteTaskAsync()
  {
    //code Here
  }
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
 {
    try
    {
        TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval, stoppingToken);
            await ExecuteTaskAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```